# How to convert byte array to text with Shift-JIS Encoding in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, encoding, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to convert a byte array to text by using Shift-JIS encoding.
But I cannot get the encoding. It says **NotSupported** exception.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis")
```

I'm using .Net Core 2.0.
What should I do?

Thanks for support

Comment: Have you installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/ ?

Comment: No. I haven't installed yet.  Oh, let me try

Comment: @HansKilian it works. I gonna put the answer below. Thank you!